# For Audiorecord, what is relationship between record time with record length(in bytes)?

Tags: android, multithreading, audiorecord

Poor enghlish i have, I hope I can express my problem clearly.
Now, I'm working one AudioTrack and AudioRecord. When I want to specify the exaclty running time for my AudioRecord thread, some problems happened. For example,if I want it(AudioRecord thread) run in a very short time, about 200 ms, the file length for this reocord will be 1 byte(for writeByte()) or 2bytes(for writeshort()). However, if I prolong the record time, more than 300ms. The file length of this sound record become 23041 bytes(for writeByte()). So, I'm really confused about what is the relationship between record time with recorded file. And why I prolong just a little bit of time for Audiotrack thread, it will come out such more bytes?